# Ethers.js handling delayed signer rejection

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js

I'm working on a site with an existing virtual currency (Let's call this VC).

I've also created an ERC20 Token (Let's call this ET) so that I can buy ET using the VC.

Since there's no way to check the user's VC amount while the transaction is ongoing, I decided to deduct the VC initially before actually creating the transaction for signing.

Because of this flow, it is normal to give back the user their VC if they decide to reject the transaction for some reason (for example, not enough gas to pay for the transaction). It's particularly easy to do this as long as the user doesn't close their browser.

The problem I have now is that if for some reason, the users accidentally closes the browser, then I wouldn't be able to detect the transaction rejection and I wouldn't be able to return the user's VC.

Any halp pls?

Comment: If VC is an off-chain property then you'll need to track from a backend service.

Comment: Hi there @Ismael thanks for the suggestion.

Could you please elaborate on the "backend service". Is there a way to get external api data from within a solidity contract? Thanks!

Comment: I'll suggest running a service to interact with off-chain assets since a contract cannot do it. It's hard to recommend something without knowing more details about VC behavior.